# Etale locally free sheaf is always locally free in Zariski topology.

Tags: schemes, coherent-sheaves

I'm trying to solve exercise III.10.5 from Hartshorne "Algebraic geometry". Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on a scheme $X$ locally free in 'etale topology', namely for any $x \in X$ there is an 'etale' map $f: U \to X$, together with a point $x' \in U$, $f(x')=x$, such that $f^* \mathcal F $ is a free $\mathcal O_U$ module, then $\mathcal F$ is locally free.

Comment: We can replace $X$ by an affine scheme and suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is not locally free then we have an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow O_{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow 0$ of $O_{X}$ and in particular localizing at the point x $I_{x} \neq 0$. But by assumption, there is an etlae neighborhood $f:U \rightarrow X$ such that $f^{\star}(I) =0 $ But etale neighborhoods are flat so they take injective map of modules to injective maps so $0 \rightarrow f*{I} \rightarrow O(U)^{n}$ is exact.